# iPhone Dev: error: cannot find protocol declaration for 'NSXMLParserDelegate'

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, build, nsxmlparser

I've got an Xcode project that I know works, but when I try to build it on a different machine, I get this error:

> error: cannot find protocol declaration for 'NSXMLParserDelegate'

along with about 90 other random syntax errors.  I wonder if it has something to do with the build configuration?  Because I can't think what else would've changed.

Appreciate any input, thanks!